# A 'contents' key is required Laravel 10 Uploading Multiple Images

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a problem with "A 'contents' key is required". I have been searching through but does not get the right answers. Here is my code

```
     $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept'=>'application/json',
    ]);
    foreach($vault->ad_images as $image){
        if(Storage::exists($image)){
            $path = Storage::path($image);
            $file = fopen($path,'r');
            $response = $response->attach('images[]',$file);
        }
    }

    $response = $response->post($apiUrl,[$data]);
    $response = json_decode($response->body(),true);
```

I have searching through about the problem, it said the the contents is required where the files is actually exists in the storage. I even trace the fopen and get this result

```
stream resource @25 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Agc/PropertyVaultController.php:564
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_type: "plainfile"
  stream_type: "STDIO"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "/home/ita/public_html/v2/storage/app/public/uploads/images/2023/11/291/395048-1700795192.jpg"
  options: []
}
```

This is really confusing since its just actually happen. Last time it works without any problem with this code.

Answer (score 0):

`attach` method accepts `name` and `contents` (string value), you pass `resourse`.

```php
$file = fopen($path,'r');
$contents = stream_get_contents($file);

$response->attach('fileName', $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#multi-part-requests) and from [api doc](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http.html#method_attach), this method you have 4 parameters. They are these:

1º `string|array` `$name`-> name of the file

2º `string|resource` `$contents` -> its contents. //ex: `file_get_contents('photo.jpg')` or `fopen('photo.jpg', 'r');`

3º `string|null` `$filename` -> file's filename

4º `array` `$headers` -> // ex: `['Accept'=>'application/json']`